# How to get a list of Wikidata entity IDs from Wikiquote

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I would like to get a list of the Q-item entity IDs for every individual person who has a wikiquote page. There is not much in the way of information on how wikiquote is integrated with wikidata and I can't find a wikidata property of "has a wikiquote page"

Comment: integration is like with any other wiki source via `schema:isPartOf` property: `SELECT DISTINCT ?wdEntity ?wqURL ?name WHERE {
  ?wqURL schema:about ?wdEntity ;
              schema:inLanguage "en" ;
              schema:name ?name ;
              schema:isPartOf [ wikibase:wikiGroup "wikiquote" ] .
 }
limit 10`

Comment: This works, could you point me to somewhere where I can find documentation for how the `schema` relation type works? it doesnt seem to be mentioned in the SPARQL tutorial at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial